# Wildcard use within Replace - Specific number of characters

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I have the following problem:

I want to replace a link to another sheet. This link changes during the Macro from "MeasData!E10" to "MeasData_XXX!E10" (XXX any number) and can be any of these during the Macro. Now I want to replace one of these with a Cell of the current sheet.

The problem is, that my cells contain more than one of the strings like above, e.g.:

```
=MeasData_110!E10*MeasData_110!E15*MeasData_110!E20
```

When using the Cells.Replace method this will correctly replace MeasData_110!E10 with the set string. However, if the link I am looking for is not in the first position, e.g.:

```
=MeasData_110!E20*MeasData_110!E10*MeasData_110!E15
```

It will be replaced to:

```
=STRING*MeasData_110!E15
```

because I am just using a wildcard:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells.Replace _
What:="MeasData*!E10", Replacement:=STRING
```

I have not yet found out if there is a wildcard for 
a) specific letters
AND
b) specific/variable number of letters (0-4)

Someone got a solution?

Comment: The only wildcards are `*` and `?`. You can use Regular Expressions but you'll need to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the quickest way is to use `Replace()` in a loop:

```
Sub MM()
Dim foundCell       As Excel.Range
Dim foundAddress    As String
Dim findString      As String
Dim replaceString   As String

findString = "MeasData!E10"
replaceString = Range("AD48").Value

Set foundCell = Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=findString, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

foundAddress = foundCell.Address
    Do
        With foundCell
            .Formula = Replace(.Formula, findString, replaceString)
        End With

        Set foundCell = Sheets(1).Cells.FindNext(foundCell)

    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

---

***Or***

You can, if you wish, use the `VBScript.RexExp` object via late binding like so:

```
Function ReplaceAllWith(old_string As String, pattern As String, new_string As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .pattern = pattern
        .Global = True
        If .Test(old_string) Then
            ReplaceAllWith = .Replace(old_string, new_string)
        Else
            ReplaceAllWith = old_string
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Insert the above into your module, and use like so:

```
For Each cell In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells
    If cell.HasFormula Then
        cell.Formula = ReplaceAllWith(cell.Formula, "MeasData(_[\d]{3})?!E10", Range("AD48").Value)
    End If
Next
```

---

Comment: The second one looks quite interesting. But I want to look for "Measdata!E10" and "Measdata_123!E10" and replace any of the two (if they are used) by cell "AD48". What you just wrote replaces "MeasData!E10" with "MeasData_123!E10" ?!

Comment: Works like a charm, RegEx expression for the search term has to be this:

`MeasData(_?[\d]{0,3})!E10`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MeasData(_[\d]{1,3})?!E10` otherwise it would match the underscore without a number. [See this example](https://regex101.com/r/iD6nX1/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the cell numbers you can use the below

Dynamically pass values for the variables Cells1,cells2 and cells3

cells1 = "110!E10"

cells2 = "110!E15"

Cells3 = "110!E20"

str1 = "=MeasData_" & cells1 & "*Measdata_" & cells2 & "*MeasData_" & Cells3

'Debug.Print str1 'Print and verify if you need

Comment: This is not really helping at all. I want to replace the whole string?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regular expressions? you need to add reference to Microsoft VBScript regular expressions 5.5 for this

```
    Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = "=MeasData_110!E20*Measdata_110!E10*MeasData_110!E15*Measdata_123!E10"
    a = ReplaceNumbers(a, "MeasData_STRING!E10")
    MsgBox a
    End Sub
    Private Function ReplaceNumbers(inputString As String, replacement As String) As String
        Pattern = "Meas[dD]ata_([0-9]{1,})\!E10"
        output = inputString
         Dim re As New RegExp
        re.Pattern = Pattern
        re.Global = True: re.MultiLine = True
        If re.test(inputString) Then
            ReplaceNumbers = re.Replace(inputString, replacement)
        Else
            ReplaceNumbers = inputString
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Thanks!